# neo4j webinterface behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, neo4j, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to expose a neo4j database to the internet.

For security reasons, I'd like to hide it behind a SSL/basic_auth combination via nginx. Here is the corresponding nginx config:

```
  location /neo4j/ {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:7473/;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;

            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
            proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
            proxy_buffering     off;
            proxy_redirect      off;
            auth_basic           "restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/htpasswd;
            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 1024;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            rewrite /neo4j/(.*) /$1 break;
    }
```

While I'm able to access https://example.com/neo4j/browser, the webinterface tells me, that it can't connect to the neo4j and my webbrowser's console gets filled up with `OPTIONS https://example.com/db/data 405(Not allowed)`

I also tried the neo4j built in https server in conjunction with the authentication extension (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension).
With this option, I also can access the webinterface.

But the interface also displays, that it's not able to connect to the neo4j and the webbrowser's console gets filled up with `OPTIONS http://example.com:7473/db/data/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` and the hint `The page at 'https://example.com:7473/browser/' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from 'http://example.com:7473/db/data/': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

Does anyone know, how to get it working? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer, but related: see https://github.com/sarmbruster/vagrant_neo4j_modproxy for a sample config using apache's mod_proxy + mod_substitute. The intersting line is https://github.com/sarmbruster/vagrant_neo4j_modproxy/blob/master/etc/apache2/sites-available/default#L8. So you need to change some contents in the http response.

Comment: thank you! that's what i tried to achieve with the rewrite directive in the nginx config... doesn't work though :(

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same problem and it's kind of weird the lack of info about Nginx as a webserver combined with neo4j. It's odd the only reference to a reverse proxy in the official doc is Apache - not impressed.

Just FYI I'm using a dockerised neo4j (https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/tree/master/2.3.2) as it comes by default (in case you want to know other settings). It should not matter if you run neo4j natively outside docker. The following Nginx conf will be the same.

```
location /neo4j/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://YOUR-IP:7474/browser/;
 }

 location /db/data/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_pass http://YOUR-IP:7474/db/data/;
}
```

Replace **YOUR-IP** by yours and change **7474** for **7473** if you are using HTTPS instead of HTTP.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The `OPTIONS` request is needed to verify the connection to the Neo4j server. I think of it as a heartbeat to verify the connection. It seems that Nginx does not support `OPTIONS` requests, but the request can be intercepted with something like this:

```
location / {
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200;
    }
}
```

Source: http://blog.rogeriopvl.com/archives/nginx-and-the-http-options-method/